# How to get query in Sql query to JPA

Tags: java, jpa

```
SELECT * FROM EL_TOD_RATES WHERE ELRS_ID=375,
```

There are more than 375 ELRS_ID foun in db,

I am using this named query

```
@NamedQuery(name="ELTodrates.getdetail",query="SELECT e1 FROM ELRateSlabs e1 WHERE e1.elrsId=:elrsId"),
```

and passing parameter to query

```
List<ELTodRates> todrates=entityManager.createNamedQuery("ELTodrates.getdetail",ELTodRates.class).getResultList();
```

but i am getting exception

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException [query] is incompatible with query return type`

Comment: Can you share compete exception trace here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are querying: `SELECT e1 FROM ELRateSlabs` (which returns a list of `ELRateSlabs`) and you want the return of the query to be `List<ELTodRates>` which is not true.

Comment: sorry for late can u help me out how to write query for this.